# How to configure my login screen to remember last session I used?

Tags: 11.04, unity, gdm, session

I'm using 11.04 and I want it to remember the last session I use, unity or ubuntu classic, where can I configure it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

After selecting the session at the Login prompt, that option will be the default upon next reboot.  [image: select session]

Comment: thank you Mikey, but it doesn't remember the last choice, it's disturbing. Is there anywhere I can edit a configure file to enable this?